# EventHandlers and C# Classes destructor/Dispose

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I'm a bit confused about C# Classes and their deconstructor.

I have to consume a few event handlers in a class instance I'm getting in the constructor:

```
 public Foo(IFooHandler handler)
 {
     handler.Load += Load;
     handler.Close += Close;
 }
```

I need to unsubscribe to that event when the Foo class is destroyed. Do I implement `IDisposable` and unsubscribe in there, or in a deconstructor? I need to consume those events, I can't do it another way.

For one of the classes, I create an instance, check progress, and then the class instance goes out of scope. For another it stays in the `MainForm` until the form is closed. The first is what I'm worried about because it may still have a reference to that event handler and not properly go.

I don't want to leak memory. When and how should I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 30):

Don't do it in the destructor, because it won't be called while the event handlers are attached : when you attach an instance method of Foo as a handler for an event of Bar, Bar will hold a reference to Foo, so Foo won't be garbage collected, and its destructor won't be called.

You should implement IDisposable, and dispose your object explicitly

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.Load -= Load;
        handler.Close -= Close;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I thought we shouldnt implement IDisposable unless we're cleaning up unmanaged code?

Comment: IDisposable can be implemented for other reasons, it's not limited to cleaning unmanaged resources...

Comment: If you take a look at the common Disposable Pattern, there is a path for handling managed and unmanaged resources. Mostly you have only unmanaged resources and / or managed ones. But for your case it is also okay just to have managed resources which should be cleaned.

Comment: To complete Oliver's comment, here's a useful link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you ever face the problem of having class A be a long lived class and class(es) B be short lived ones that subscribe to events of class A then you probably would be interested in the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx). It can be a problem that you do not discover is one until it is to late i.e. [Princeton self driving car.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/IfOnlyWedUsedANTSProfiler.aspx)

Comment: Ha ha ha. Great link to the self-driving memory leak. I was dealing with static event handlers on a project and wondered if all the fuss was worth it. This link made my day.